# How to show an Image in Mytoolkit Grid conditionally in UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, win-universal-app

I am using [MyToolKit Grid](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid) in my uwp app. So in one column of that grid I am displaying the image/icon. Now I want to show that image based on specific condition.Did any one have idea about this?
In the following code I want to show the **admin.png** conditionally.

The code I have used for Grid and Icon is:

```
    <Border x:Name="WideMainGrid" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"  Margin="10,-5,5,0">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="svCartItemsList" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="8">
                            <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dgNewBill" RowBackgroundEvenBrush="Black" RowBackgroundOddBrush="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding objStockIssueItemList}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="470" SelectionMode="Single" TabNavigation="Local" HeaderBackground="Black" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Margin="0,0,0,0" Loading="dgNewBill_Loading">

 <controls:DataGrid.Columns>

                                    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SNumber}" Width="0.7*" CanSort="False" Foreground="White">

                                        <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                <!--<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"></Setter>-->
                                            </Style>
                                        </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                                    </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource myCellTemplateMonth}"  Width="3*" x:Name="ItemDesc"  CanSort="False" IsAscendingDefault="True">

                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>


                                    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding uom}" Width="0.7*" CanSort="False" Foreground="White">

                                        <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"></Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                                    </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="0.7*" CanSort="False">

                                        <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Name="pricePanel"  Height="30" Tapped="pricePanel_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                                    <TextBlock Name="price" Foreground="White"  Text='{Binding editedPrice}' TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="1.2*" CanSort="False">

                                        <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Name="quantityPanel"  Height="30" Tapped="quantityPanel_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                    <TextBlock Name="quantity" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"  Text='{Binding quantity}' HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="0.7*" CanSort="False">

                                        <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Name="discountPanel"  Height="30" Tapped="discountPanel_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                                    <TextBlock Name="Discount" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text='{Binding discount}' HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

                                    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cartTotal}" Width="0.7*" CanSort="False" Foreground="White">

                                        <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>

                                            </Style>
                                        </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                                    </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

                                    <!--delete image column-->
                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn CanSort="False" Width="0.7*">
                                        <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                                    <StackPanel x:Name="voidImagePanel" Tapped="voidImagePanel_Tapped">
                                                        <Image x:Name="VoidImage" Source="{Binding imageUrl}" Height="25" Width="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,2,0,0"></Image>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                    <StackPanel Height="28" Name="salesPersonDetails" Tapped="salesPersonDetails_Tapped">
                                                        <Image x:Name="salesDetail" Source="/Images/admin.png" Height="22" Width="35"  Margin="0,2,0,0"></Image>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </StackPanel>

                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

                                </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                            </controls:DataGrid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
```

Comment: Is it a data-related condition or a interaction behavior condition?

Comment: data-related condition.I  will get some value from database based on that I have to show the image.

Comment: Several options possible, but easiest is just bind the Visibility property of the image control to a bool prop in your DataContext. Could be you need to use a BoolToVisibilityConverter but that is easy too.

Comment: can u explain some more briefly..... We  can't access this image in code behind file.

Comment: The image source is `ms-appx:///Images/admin.png` not `/Images/admin.png`

Comment: I am storing the image in Images folder located in project. that s y  url  is:  /Images/admin.png